# List of competitions at Tokyo 2020 Olympics

Tags: data-request, sports

I am looking for the list of competitions of the Tokyo 2020 Olympics.

- Place
- Time
- Sport
- Name
- Official booking URL if available
- More info is welcome

It does not have to evolve in real-time, even though regular updates would be great.
Needs to be reusable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official source for Olympic data is http://odf.olympictech.org/

This site does not yet have any references to the Tokyo olympics.